# React Relay fetch list

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

I need to fetch list
I have Schema

```js
export const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {      
      activities: {
        name: 'Activities',
        type: new GraphQLList(activityType),
        resolve: (root, args, { rootValue }) => {
          return User.findById(rootValue.req.user.id)
            .populate('activities')
            .then((user) => user.activities);
        },
      },
```

When I do graphql request using curl and sends

```
query ActivitiesQuery {
    activities {
        name
    }
}
```

it gives me

```
{
  "data": {
    "activities": [
     {
        "name": "Eat"
     }
     ]
  }
}
```

Can somebody give me example how can I fetch it using relay ? because all the examples give object and then list like Store: { teas: [...

Answer (score 0):

`activities` is an example of a *plural non-identifying field*. It is plural in the sense that it returns a list of things, and non-identifying in the sense that the individual elements of that list are not identified by global IDs.

Relay does not support plural non-identifying fields at the root, but support is coming. Follow along at https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/112